# Generating functions for catastrophe theory

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics, classical-mechanics, catastrophe-theory

I am studying Thom's theorem in catastrophe theory and am having a hard time understanding what the "generating functions" actually do. How exactly are they used to classify generic caustics? The literature I am being exposed to is mostly physics-related so doesn't have very rigorous mathematical discussion. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: Note: there are two very different meanings of the phrase 'generating function'. The meaning intended by the tag refers to formal power series ([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). But it's also used in classical mechanics, where their purpose is to generate particular canonical transformations ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Generating_function_approach). I can't find a definitive reference to settle which usage is intended in catastrophe theory, but given the links to dynamical systems I'd suspect it's actually the latter.

Comment: Given the connection to physics, you might consider the physics or mathematical-physics tags. The dynamical-systems tag may also be useful. On the other hand, I suspect the generating-function tag isn't actually appropriate here.

Comment: Hm, ok I'll try changing it. Unfortunately there didn't seem to be any pre-made tags that really applied.